# What is the proper volume to weight conversion for Bisquick?

Tags: flour, measurements

Most recipes that call for Bisquick have volume measurements, but I've read it's better to measure most dry ingredients by mass (not to mention more convenient and less messy). So what is the proper conversion factor for Bisquick (i.e. it's density)?

I assume it's close to that of flour, but [different types of flours have different densities](http://www.traditionaloven.com/conversions_of_measures/flour_volume_weight.html) and I wasn't sure which one to use or which one the Bisquick manufacturers assume when developing their recipes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The General Mills site has the [image](http://www.generalmills.com/~/media/Images/Brands/Nutritional_Images/Betty_Crocker/Bisquick/Bisquick_Original.JPG) of the "original" pancake mix along with it's nutrition facts.

The serving size is 1/3 cup mix (40 g)

This means that one cup of the mix should weigh 120 g (4-1/4 oz).

[image: Bisquick Nutrition Facts]

Answer (score 3):

Do you have a scale and measuring cup? Weigh a cup of Bisquick.

Also, [this site](http://stason.org/TULARC/food/cooking/2-7-5-Weight-Volume-Conversion-Chart.html) has a line for Bisquick, but I'm not sure how trustworthy it is, being from a "forgotten source". Anyway, the site says Bisquick is 130g/cup, and also lists the conversion in a number of other units.

Comment: Well right, obviously I could do that. But the whole point of weighing dry ingredients is that various factors can influence my measurement: relative humidity, how much it's packed, if it's sifted, etc. My understanding is that bakers weight ingredients because it's the mass that matters, and portioning dry by volume is only done because it's often more convenient. I'm looking for a reference of the canonical density of Bisquick.

Comment: Well be careful with your measurement. Fluff it up with a whisk and scoop gently. Weigh it from a freshly-opened pouch that hasn't had a chance to pick up moisture.

Answer (score 3):

My recipes with buisquick work just fine and I generally find that 4 cups of buisquick weigh 500 g.

Comment: This happens to be the same value that the calculator I linked to in my question gives for all-purpose flour. Good to know.

Answer (score 0):

I sifted the bisquick and them measured very carefully one cup--on my electronic scale (caliberated of course) the weight was 4 ounces.  I repeated this three times with the same results.